# Enter, Backspace, Tab and navigation keys don't work on C-Free

Tags: c++, c, windows

I installed C-Free software and for the first time all the keys worked normally. However, the next day when i wanted to use c-free again my Enter, Backspace, Tab and navigation keys didn't work. I tried to reinstall, but the result was still nil. I have checked those keys, and they work in other applications except C-Free. Do you guys know how to solve it? Thank you in advance.

I tried to reinstall and checked those keys, they work in other applications except C-Free but still not working after reinstall.

Comment: That program looks like it bundles ancient versions of compilers. Do yourself a favor and get Visual Studio Community. (not Code)

Comment: Or any somewhat modern IDE. If you were to buy a new computer, would you buy one from 2010? If not then why would you pick a compiler from that time - it is _exactly_ the same thing. Notably there has been one major and one minor revision of C since that IDE was last updated, and 3 major revisions of C++.

Comment: Use either Visual Studio Code or Visual Studio. C-Free looks ancient.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Visual Studio Code, Neovim. C-Free, is and old IDE,

- To leverage the best of Visual Studio Code, try using plugins that will help u while coding in c.
- For Neovim. You can try to build your own config. Or try an existing config like lunarvim.org